# How to find the owner Solana NFT in the past timestamp?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

Understanding that it is pretty straightforward to fetch the current owner of a NFT on Solana ([get holder of solana nft using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209764/get-holder-of-solana-nft-using-python)), how could we get the owner at certain timestamp in the past?

One way I could think of is to get all the transfer transactions of a particular NFTs and sort all the `from` address by time. Just wondering if there are better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pitched approach is the only possible one currently: Going through all transactions and filter them.

You could for example check how the solana explorer is doing it in the Token Transfer Tab: [github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/edefaa437f136479774e556f4d429d653198a0b1/explorer/src/components/account/history/TokenTransfersCard.tsx#L248)